# how to reset password in fresh installed laravel 5?

Tags: email, laravel, authentication, passwords, reset

i have just installed laravel5 and migrate the users table and inserted the users in table.

now i want to change the password using password reset in laravel5.
when is use the email to reset the password the bootbox alert is seen saying We have e-mailed your password reset link!. but, actually email is not being sent.

i have used the mandrill for email purpose in that project, i want to reset password.anyone here who  knows how to reset password sending password in laravel 5?

Comment: Why do you want to send password-reset emails for a migration?

Answer (score 1):

Run this in your controller function,

```
$password = "123456";
$new_password   = Hash::make($password);
return $new_password;
```

This will return the hashed new password. replace the new password with password field of users table.

Comment: Easy and efficient:-)

Comment: Actually the OP has problems with sending password-reset emails. I don't think he has the original passwords at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `php artisan tinker` to write some php code directly from the command line and change your password, e.g.:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->password = \Hash::make($password);
$user->save();
```